# How to detect a click event in my case

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, modal-dialog

I am trying to pop a modal on the parent controller and do something to the child after use click a button

For example,
child controller

```
$scope.openModal = function(){
    var item = 'my first item'
    $scope.showItem(item);

    //I want to do something here after user clicks 'Click me' button
})
```

Parent controller

```
$scope.showItem = function(item){
    $modal({
                template: 'item-modal.html',
                scope: $scope,                
          });
})
```

In my item-modal.html

```
//other html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="confirm()">Click me</button>
```

So I want the child be able to know parent's action which is the modal button being clicked. Is there a way to do this? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to events via `$broadcast` to listen to events down the parent chain.

```
// Parent controller
$scope.confirm = function() {
  $scope.broadcast("myTestEvent", {'key':'value'});
}


// Child controller
$scope.$on("myTestEvent", function(data) {
  console.log("Event from parent fired with data as : " + data );
})
```

Comment: I am trying to avoid broadcast as it's not the best practice for angular. thanks though

Answer (score 1):

angular-ui modal, right ?

If so, the $modal api returns a promise resolving when the modal is closed with either $close ( success ) or $dismiss ( failure ). See https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal for more info, or https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q for infos about promises.

So this would pretty much looks like this :

```
$scope.openModal = function(){
    var item = 'my first item'
    $scope.showItem(item).then(function(result) {
      // DO something with result
    });
});
```

Parent controller

```
$scope.showItem = function(item){
    return $modal({
                template: 'item-modal.html',
                scope: $scope,                
          });
})
```

In my item-modal.html

```
//other html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="$close(myResult)">Click me</button>
```

or use your own method as the ng-click handler which would call $scope.$close with whatever you want to pass back as the promise result.

Comment: +1 so if I want to use my own method without passing params in my modal.html, can I do ng-click='clickme()'

Comment: yep, with the clickme() method calling $close or $dismiss to close the modal with the result you wanna pass back to your child

Comment: i see. However, the result returns from the promise are the entire item-modal.html instead of the method's myResult. Could you please clarify that for me?